# How to achieve the effect disappearance / appearance of the action bar? (Google Now effect)

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I would like to reproduce the effect of appearance and disappearance of the action bar that carries the Google Application Now.

**Exist there a library (GitHub project) to achieve this effect?**

1) Initially, the action bar appears normally.

2) Then, as soon as you scroll down the listView action bar disappears.

3) And then, as soon as you scroll up the action bar appears again.

[image: Google Now action bar effect]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called **Quick Return**. See this [blog post](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/an-emerging-ui-pattern-quick-return.html) for details on the pattern. There is also a link to an implementation by Google developers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this link](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/) can be usefull: it shows how to change ActionBar color while you scroll on layout. You want to achieve the opposite one, so you have to change a little the code. Personally i didn't try this code, but the blogger is a very good developer!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already know this library, but it's not quite what I want. I wanted to know if anyone has already done this work before.(+1 anyway)

Comment: @lopez.mikhael thank you! If you are looking on a library (GitHub project) then look at this one: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/05/fading-actionbar/ this is based on link of my answer. Of course is a little different, but it is better then nothing!